# implementing multi-language support in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-router, i18next

I'm building a small eCommerce solution using moltin API for the backend and ReactJS for the frontend. I have already finished my application and I would like to implement the Spanish language. Users should be able to click the Spanish flag and the website (all components) would immediately be translated into Spanish.

I have tried many npm packages, but none worked - I don't use Redux, I just have a bunch of ReactJS components, Layout file, and Routes. I already saw some examples on how to accomplish this when you have one component, but I still don't know how can I change the language in different components.

I'm using react-router too.

Comment: You can maintain a JSON file which contains mapping for en-spanish and when someone clicks on spanish flag the page reloads and all your text which was english will now be in spanish.
The text for all your components should be something like languages["es"]["buttonText"]>
An approach like this can work for you.
Just import your json file in your components.

Comment: I already imported the json files with the languages, but what should exactly happen when somebody clicks on the Spanish flag? How should the components know which language they should render (all together)?

Comment: You can keep the locale info inside queryParams. Not the most ideal solution but can work.

Comment: Basically, you need to have a `translate` function as a React context so that all components inside can make use of this function. Of course, the `translate` function needs to know your current language and the translation hash.

Comment: Already tagged with i18next...use react-i18next. Takes care for loading the translations - and triggering rerender on language change: Have a look at the samples: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example or doucmentation: https://react.i18next.com . Having questions reach me over at gibhub (maintaining both i18next and react-i18next).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using react-x18n npm package. It's easy to use and solved all translation problems. Once the click function is triggered and the language is changed, all components are translated in one second!